# How to parse and print Nested array value from JSON format

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to parse and print below JSON but there's problem while printing.

JSON Format is :

```
{"categories": 
[
  "Firewall Permit","Custom Policy 1"
]
}
```

I used to below code to achieve this but i can print only "Firewall Permit"

```
>>> for x in json_data:
    line1 = (x['categories'][0])
    print (line1)

Firewall Permit
```

But i want to print like: `Firewall Permit, Custom Policy`

Please guide me on this. How to use this JSON Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the capabilities of the Python 3 `print` function:

```
for entry in json_data:
    print(*entry['categories'], sep=', ')
```

prints:

```
Firewall Permit, Custom Policy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this simple way:

```
print(', '.join(json_data['categories']))
```